# Why cannot get different information for each icon with ajax and popover?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson, popover

Here is js function, after selecting a station this function is called, and icons are created (randomly coming data according to Stations.php) and showed in the html page.The icons are also binding with popover by calling bindMyPopovers() function, to show popups when coming to icon:

```
 function sta_callStation(sel){
  $('#noOfPassengers, #infoOfPassengers, #distType,#distParams').empty();
   $('#sta_numberOfIcons').empty();


    $.getJSON('Stations.php?id='+sel.value, function(station){

        $.each(station, function(sta_key, sta_value) {

        if(sel.value==sta_key)
        {
          $.each(sta_value.passengers, function(j,passengers) 
        {



          //$('#sta_numberOfIcons').append('<i class="icon-user" ></i>');
         var pas_icon = document.createElement("a");

          pas_icon.className ="icon-user";
          pas_icon.id='id_'+j;

          pas_icon.setAttribute('href', '#');
          pas_icon.setAttribute('rel', 'popover');
          //alert('id_'+(j));
          var empty=document.createElement("a");
          empty.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
          document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(pas_icon);

          document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(empty);

      });
        }
   });
       bindMyPopovers();
  });
  }
function bindMyPopovers() {
$("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){

    $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title:"Passenger Information",
        content: "Passenger "+$(this).attr('id')+" "+showPassenger($(this))
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });
 });
}
```

Here is the showPassenger to get the data from Passengers.php with passengerId (in the icons they have also id) and I want to show the coming data in the content of the related popup.

```
  var v;
 function showPassenger($this){      
  $("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){
  var id=$this.attr('id');
  var id_num=id.charAt(id.length-1);      

  $.getJSON('Passengers.php?passengerId='+id_num, function(passenger){
      v=null;
      $.each(passenger, function(pas_key, pas_value) {

          v+=" "+pas_key+" "+pas_value+" ";

      });


   });});return v;}
```

With this code, first I select a station from the stations combobox, then icons are created, but when I come to an icon, for example  the content shows; Passenger id_1 undefined.Then the second selection I get some information about passenger(for example from:2, to:3).But for the other passenger icons the same data shown in the content of their popup.Why is the same data bound for all the icons? How can I change the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function sta_callStation(sel){
 var numberOfPassengers=0;
 $('#noOfPassengers, #infoOfPassengers, #distType,#distParams').empty();
     $('#sta_numberOfIcons').empty();

      stationId=sel.value;
      stationId++;
      $.getJSON('Stations.php?id='+sel.value, function(station){

          $.each(station, function(sta_key, sta_value) {

          if(sel.value==sta_key)
          {
            $.each(sta_value.passengers, function(j,passengers) 
          {
            numberOfPassengers++;
            var pas_icon = document.createElement("a");

            pas_icon.className ="icon-user";
            pas_icon.id=(j+1);

            pas_icon.setAttribute('href', '#');
            pas_icon.setAttribute('rel', 'popover');

            var empty=document.createElement("a");
            empty.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
            document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(pas_icon);

            document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(empty);

        });
            $("#noOfPassengers").append("Yolcu Sayısı:"+numberOfPassengers);
          }
     });
         sta_bindMyPopovers();
    });
    }

 function sta_bindMyPopovers() {
 $("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){
      sta_showPassenger($(this).attr('id'));
  });
 }

 var v='';
 function sta_showPassenger(id){     
    var id_num=id;      
    console.log("id: " + id);
    console.log("id_num: " + id_num);
    $.getJSON('Passengers.php/'+id_num, function(passenger){
        console.log("passenger: " + passenger );
        v='';
        $.each(passenger, function(pas_key, pas_value) {

            v+=" "+pas_key+" "+pas_value+" ";

        });

        $("#"+id).popover({
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          html: true,
          title:"Passenger "+ id_num ,
          content: " " + v
      })
      .click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });

  });

   console.log("v: " + v);
  return v;
}
```